# certificate verify failed error in python

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to access a https site internal to our corporate network. 
It's giving me the following error.

```
    res = self.opener.open('https://%s/' % self.host, urllib.urlencode(data))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

I am working on mac os x and I've updated my openssl version.

the output of  `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` is `OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does `internal` site mean that it's using a self-signed cert?

Comment: No it's not a self signed certificate